# Why is a Spring ProxyFactoryBean implicit definition working?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following definition:

```
<bean id="myInterceptor" class="info.fastpace.MyInterceptor"/>

<bean id="alikProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="myClass"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>myInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have 2 classes defined: `MyInterceptor` and `MyClass`.

The peculiar thing is that Spring knows to invoke the interceptor before invoking class `MyClass` (capital M), even though the class isn't configured in the commonContext.xml file. The only hint is the `myClass` (lowercase m) in the proxy bean definition.

When removing the alikProxy bean definition, the interceptor isn't invoked.

How does Spring know to invoke the interceptor for `MyClass` using an **undefined** `myClass` ref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you defined a bean of class `MyClass`, but did not give it any name explicitly, so Spring just gave it a default name `myClass`, based on class name `MyClass`.

**Update**
I suppose somewhere in your Spring context xml you have `<context:component-scan>` element.

Here is a fragment of book [Spring In Action, 3rd Edition](http://www.manning.com/walls4/):

> By default, `<context:component-scan>` looks for classes that are annotated with one
>   of a handful of special stereotype annotations:
>
> - `@Component`—A general-purpose stereotype annotation indicating that the class
>     is a Spring component
>
> *...skipped...*
>
> For example, suppose that our application context only has the `eddie` and `guitar` beans in it. We can eliminate the explicit `<bean>` declarations from the XML configuration by using `<context:component-scan>` and annotating the `Instrumentalist` and `Guitar` classes with `@Component`.
>
> *...skipped...*
>
> When Spring scans the `com.springinaction.springidol` package, it’ll find that
>   `Guitar` is annotated with `@Component` and will automatically register it in Spring. **By default, the bean’s ID will be generated by camel-casing the class name.** In the case of `Guitar` that means that the bean ID will be `guitar`.

Comment: I didn't define any bean for class 'MyClass'.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Could you pls show your `MyClass`'s implementation?

Comment: what are you expecting to find there?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka e.g., some Spring annotation. If `ref="myClass"` works, then bean `myClass` exists.

Comment: I have an annotation over the class: `@Component`. Without params.
Meaning, `@org.springframework.stereotype.Component`. That's it.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka So, this is the reason. Spring sees a `@Component` annotation and creates a bean of this class. Since you use it without params (i.e. do not give it an explicit name), Spring give it a default name - `myClass`.